# How exactly iam-user-unused-credentials-check works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, config, amazon-iam

I've recently implemented some compliance in a company but one rule messed up my mind.
It is about **iam-user-unused-credentials-check** that, at least according to docs, should enter non-compliant if IAM user has used neither password not access key for configured amount of time.

Well, I do have a user that used his login credentials to access web console and it's stil
marked as non-compliant? I ran manually re-evaluate couple of minutes after that fact but still resource is non-compliant :/.

Should I give it more time and re-eveluate again in few hours? Or did I misunderstood what this rule does or how does it to that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understand what happened.
With this particular rule, AWS Config does not rely on configuration changes it records but on AWS Cloud Trail to see an activity. That's one.
The other one was the timeout that had to pass to pick up a trail (heh). After a while, resource just went compliant.